# How to add pages into white list by categories in MediaWiki?

Tags: configuration, mediawiki, access-control, mediawiki-extensions

I am maintaining a private site based on MediaWiki with the following [configurations](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights#Examples).

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read']=false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['read']=true;
```

In this case, how should I make pages in some category (e.g., Category:OpenAccess) publicly readable?

The version info is as follows:

- MediaWiki: [1.25.2 (a5c188b)](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_1.25)
- PHP: 5.3.3 (apache2handler)
- MySQL: 5.1.73

---

The code using [Extension:CategoryPermissions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryPermissions) below [(demonstrated in this example)](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryPermissions#Changes_to_LocalSettings.php) does not work.

```
$wgGroupDefaultAllow=true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['Category:OpenAccess_read']=true;
```

Comment: What version of MediaWiki are you using? That extension is incredibly old, and for instance I would have expected it to be `&$title, &$user, $action, &$result`, not `$title, $user, $action, $result` in the `checkCategoryPermissions` function call. I would not expect the code to work in recent MediaWiki versions

Comment: @leo MediaWiki: 1.25.2, PHP: 5.3.3, and MySQL: 5.1.73. Added to the post. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Did you try with `&$title, &$user, $action, &$result`? Also, anything in the error log?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using [$wgWhitelistReadRegexp](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgWhitelistReadRegexp).

Try putting something like this in your LocalSettings.php to whitelist the entire Category namespace:

```
$wgWhitelistReadRegexp = array("/Category:.*/");
```

Comment: `$wgWhitelistReadRegexp` does not work for me. Perhaps categories are not namespaces.